# How to get bootstrap modal size

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal whose size is set by:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

I want to be able to determine the modal's size (width actually) before I make a post request to a PHP program to display some dynamic content before displaying the modal. Does anyone know how to get this information?

Comment: $('.modal-lg').height()

Comment: @johnSmith That almost works. I get the correct value when at full screen. However, when I make the window narrower than 580 (the initial value) it returns -20 for all modal widths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the actual dimensions of an element using Javascript, JQuery has the built in `.width()` and `.height()` functions. I modified your `<div>` to add a `data-` attribute that has the bootstrap class incase you want to access that and an ID for easier access:

```
<div id="my_modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" data-size="modal-lg">
```

Then access it via Javascript:

```
var width = $("#my_modal").width();
var height = $("#my_modal").height();
var size = $("#my_modal").attr("data-size");
console.log("Width Is: " + width + " and Height Is:" + height + "and Size Is:" + size);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tim, I spoke too soon. I was fooled by a smaller screen width. The modal width is initially always the width of the screen - 17 pixels when it first starts. If I then reduce the width of the window it appears to scale and report the width correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. When are you calling this function to check the width? When it is open or when it is not displayed? Cause I think that may address your issue.

Comment: Trying calling it after you open it, see if that reports the correct width. Also, consider making a Bootply or JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue and allow me access to debug your issue. Edit - Please make a JSFiddle of this issue, then I will look into it more.

Comment: Nope, that returns the screen width.

Answer (score 11):

I have also been trying to find either the width or height of the entire modal as well as the modal classes and found this solution. Though I must add that with this approach the width and height of the modal are only found **after** it has loaded.

I think that it is not possible to get the correct width and height of the modal **before** it is being displayed since it is hidden by default **before** the user clicks to open it. `style="display: none;` as inline style under the modal class in Bootstrap 3.3.2.

However if you like to get the correct width and height of modal once it is displayed you can use this approach.

```
    // once the modal has loaded all calculations can start
    // since the modal is hidden before it is loaded there are
    // no dimesions that can be calculated unfortunately
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {


        // get the viewport height
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        console.log ('viewportHeight = ' + viewportHeight);


        // get the viewport width
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log ('viewportWidth = ' + viewportWidth);


        // get the .modal-dialog height and width
        // here the .outerHeight() method has to be used instead of the .height() method
        // see https://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/ and
        // https://api.jquery.com/outerheight/ for reference

        // also the .find() method HAS to be used, otherwise jQuery won't find
        // the correct element, this is why you got strange values beforehand
        var modalDialogHeight = $(this).find('.modal-dialog').outerHeight(true);
        console.log ('modalDialogHeight = ' + modalDialogHeight);

        var modalDialogWidth = $(this).find('.modal-dialog').outerWidth(true);
        console.log ('modalDialogWidth = ' + modalDialogWidth);


        // I have included a simple function to log the width and height
        // of the modal when the browser window is being resized
        var modalContentWidthHeight = function () {

            var modalContentWidth = $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').outerWidth(true);
                console.log ('modalContentWidth = ' + modalContentWidth);

            var modalContentHeight = $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').outerHeight(true);
                console.log ('modalContentHeight = ' + modalContentHeight);     
            };

        $(window).resize(modalContentWidthHeight);

    });
```

I hope the above code somehow helps you figure out the modal dimensions and that you can take it from there..

Another thing that was really **bugging** me that you might encounter when using the Bootstrap 3.3.2 modal. If you like to get rid of this bug  [Open modal is shifting body content to the left #9855](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855)  concerning the modal position and given this bug it still not fixed  [Modify scrollbar check, stop static nav shift #13103](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13103)  you can use this approach that works regardless of if you have a vertical scrollbar shown or not.

Reference: [Bootstrap 3.3.2 Center modal on all viewport sizes with or without vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716986/bootstrap-3-3-2-center-modal-on-all-viewport-sizes-with-or-without-vertical-scro)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {        

// meassure the padding-right given by BS and apply it as padding-left to the modal
// like this equal padding on either side of the modal is given regardless of media query
var modalPaddingRight = $('#myModal').css('padding-right');
console.log ('modalPaddingRight = ' + modalPaddingRight);


// apply the padding value from the right to the left
$('#myModal').css('padding-left', modalPaddingRight);
console.log ( 
        'modalPaddingLeft = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-left') +
        ' modalPaddingRight = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-right')
        );


// apply equal padding on window resize
var modalPaddingLeft = function () {

    var modalPaddingRight = $('#myModal').css('padding-right');
    console.log ('modalPaddingRight = ' + modalPaddingRight);

    $('#myModal').css('padding-left', modalPaddingRight);
    console.log ( 
        'modalPaddingLeft = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-left') +
        'modalPaddingRight = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-right')
        );
};

$(window).resize(modalPaddingLeft);
});
```

I hope some of this answer can help you. Since I am new to jQuery there might be better or more elegant ways to actually code this, though I would not know how at this stage. Nevertheless I think the information given here might be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I figured out some sort of work around before.

Comment: @mlewis54 Does this work around allow you to get the width and height of the modal **before** it is being loaded? If so would be good to see a fiddle or something, thanks.